# Angular router navigation problems

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm having trouble understanding how the Angular Router.

Here's my issue:
I'm currently in this url/route -

```
https://localhost:4200/#/db/accounts/resetpassword?userId=7&resetToken=xyz
```

When I navigate using the Router + ActivatedRoute

```
this._router.navigate(['login'], { relativeTo: this._actRoute })
this._router.navigate(['./login'], { relativeTo: this._actRoute })
this._router.navigate(['../login'], { relativeTo: this._actRoute })
this._router.navigate(['../../login'], { relativeTo: this._actRoute })
```

...I get sent to

```
https://localhost:4200/#/db/accounts/resetpassword/login
```

When I navigate to

```
this._router.navigate(['../../../login'], { relativeTo: this._actRoute })
```

...I get sent to

```
https://localhost:4200/#/db/accounts/login
```

...which is where I want to be sent to.

My question is, how come the last one replaces the end segment of the url and the previous 4 don't.
I feel like I'm missing some fundamental piece of how routing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested this is how I'm solving it now. I don't really trust

```
this._router.navigate(['../../../login'], { relativeTo: this._actRoute })
```

because from different modules this works

```
this._router.navigate(['../../login'], { relativeTo: this._actRoute })
```

If anyone knows a better way please comment.
Also this might need some extra checks for fragments etc.

```
        import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    //-------------------------------------------------//

    /**
     * Replaces everything after the last '/' in currentUrl with replacementSegment.    
     * Will also remove any paramaters. 
     * @param currentUrl url to change
     * @param replacementSegment what to put at the end of the altered url
     * @returns the altered url
     */
    export function ReplaceLastUrlSegment(currentUrl: string, replacementSegment: string): string {

        if (!currentUrl)
            return '/' + replacementSegment

        //remove any paramaters
        const segments = currentUrl.split('?')
        if (!segments?.length)
            return '/' + replacementSegment

        return segments[0].split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/') + '/' + replacementSegment


    }//ReplaceLastUrlSegment

    //-------------------------------------------------//

    /**
     * Replaces everything after the last '/' in router.url with replacementSegment.    
     * Will also remove any paramaters. 
     * @param router current router
     * @param replacementSegment what to put at the end of the altered url
     * @returns the router's altered url
     */
    export function ReplaceLastUrlSegmentFromRouter(router: Router, replacementSegment: string): string {


        //Don't null check it.
        //It should crash if router is null
        return ReplaceLastUrlSegment(router.url, replacementSegment)

    }//ReplaceLastUrlSegmentFromRouter

    //-------------------------------------------------//

    /**
     * Replaces everything after the last '/' in router.url with replacementSegment.  Then navigates to new url.
     * Will also remove any paramaters. 
     * @param router current router
     * @param replacementSegment what to put at the end of the altered url
     */
    export function ReplaceLastUrlSegmentAndNavigate(router: Router, replacementSegment: string) {

        //Don't null check it.
        //It should crash if router is null

        const newUrl = ReplaceLastUrlSegment(router?.url, replacementSegment)
        router.navigateByUrl(newUrl)


    }//ReplaceLastUrlSegmentFromRouter

    //-------------------------------------------------//
```